# ErrorException Undefined offset: 0 laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, barryvdh

in my laravel project the barryvdh debugger was installed, I was trying to make pdf using barryvdh pdf package for that i run the composer command on my dev server which was

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

after that it was showing an error of class not found for that i used the command

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

after that it is showing an error
ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined offset: 0
ErrorException
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php1802

it is showing the error on dev server.All the API are working fine but web views are not working.
please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please `cache` clear first

Comment: cleared the cache,config,route but it is not working.@ A.A Noman

Comment: Please share more details, and how this question is related to Composer

Comment: I installed the same project from server to mylocal and when i run the command composer dump autoload it fixed the problem but not working on server

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

try this :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it